# I want change variable to value of hashtables in arraylist

Tags: c#, arraylist, hashtable

I made [Hashtable hash] such as

```
hash(i, 1)
hash(j, 2)
```

Also I made an [arraylist sArray] which include "i" or "j" such as

```
sArray[0] : hello                 
sArray[1] : first number is i  
sArray[2] : second number is j  
sArray[3] : bye
```

Now, I want to change the "i" and "j" in the sArray to the values of the hash.
How can I do it?

Comment: There is no explicit way to do this. Explain the use case better. Maybe there is no need of two collections

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly, I think this is the code in c#

```
//Your example
int i = 1;
int j = 2;

var hash = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
hash[i] = -173.5;
hash[j] = 37;

var sArray = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
sArray.Add("hello");
sArray.Add("first number is " + hash[i].ToString());
sArray.Add("second number is " + hash[j].ToString());
sArray.Add("bye");

// more general, you could have different i and j position
i = 3;
j = 4;

hash[i] = 33.3;
hash[j] = -44.4;

sArray[1] = "number in " + i.ToString() + " position is " + hash[i].ToString();
sArray[2] = "number in " + j.ToString() + " position is " + hash[j].ToString();

// I think following option is more easy to read and fast if iterated
i = 5;
j = 6;

hash[i] = 55.5;
hash[j] = -66.6;

sArray[1] = String.Format("number in {0} position is {1}", i, hash[i]);
sArray[2] = String.Format("number in {0} position is {1}", j, hash[j]);
```